# ¿Por qué las "calderas de Pedro Botero" es el infierno?

Tags: etimología, historia, locuciones

En el Diccionario de la lengua española, en el lema [*caldera*](https://dle.rae.es/caldera?) aparece:

> **las calderas de Pedro, o Pero, Botero**
>
> 1. locs. susts. f. pl. coloqs. En la tradición cristiana, el infierno (‖ lugar de castigo eterno).

En el diccionario de Covarrubias (consultable a través del [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) aparece: "Caldera de Pero Botello, se toma por el infierno: fundase en algun particular que yo no alcanço; sospecho devia sr algun tintorero caudaloso, que hizo qual que caldera capacissima."

El [Diccionario de Autoridades](https://webfrl.rae.es/DA.html) (1729), por su parte, cita a Covarrubias:

> CALDERA DE PERO BOTERO. Se llama vulgar y jocosamente al infierno. Covarr. le llama Pero Botello, y sospecha debió de ser algún tintorero, que hizo alguna caldera grande [ii.63] mas de lo regular.

La edición del Diccionario de la lengua española siguiente, de 1780, recoge:

> CALDERA DE PERO BOTERO: El vulgo llama así al infierno. *Infernus, tartarus.*

Pero ninguna indicación de su origen

En el Vocabulario de Refranes y Frases Proverbiales de Gonzalo Correas (2ª ed, 1924, pág 570) en cambio, viene recogido:
**En  las  ollas  de  Pero  Botello.**
En  las  calderas;  tómalas  el  vulgo  por tinas  infernales  de  fuego  y penas:  dicen que  comenzó  de  un  rico-hombre  de  pendón y caldera, y después  Maestre  de  Alcánta­ra  que  desbarató  muchas  veces a  los  mo­ros  con  varios  ardides, y coció  muchas  ve­ces  cabezas de  ellos  en  unas  grandes  calderas,  y   sería  para  presentarlas, y dicen  que los  despeñaba  en  una  sima  u  olla  muy  pro­funda.

¿Es este el origen la expresión?

Answer (score 1):

Todos los artículos que estoy encontrando por Internet al respecto, incluyendo [uno aparecido en la revista de la RAE](http://revistas.rae.es/brae/article/view/52/200) que analiza un poema que aparece en una obra titulada *Periquillo el de las gallineras*, y que hace uso de la expresión, hacen mención tanto a la definición de Covarrubias como al artículo de Gonzalo de Korreas que ya has citado, escrito originalmente en 1627. No encuentro otras explicaciones.

Entiendo que al ser una explicación tan antigua, más cercana a la fecha en la que pudo originarse el dicho, bien pudiera al menos tener algo de verdad, y que realmente existió alguien llamado Pero Botero o parecido, maestre de Alcántara o de la [Orden de Alcántara](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_de_Alc%C3%A1ntara), y que la gente comparara con el mismo diablo. Sin embargo, no veo ningún nombre parecido en la lista de maestres de la Orden.

El caso más antiguo que encuentro de la expresión es el siguiente:

> *Filaletes.- [...] y ved vos si hablé como debí, recatándome que a vueltas de las yerbas, que como bien para suplemento de la poca carne, que Marquillos me echa en la olla, me dé la del rejalgar, con que me envíe al caldero de Pero Botello.*
>
> *Pánfilo.- No permita Dios vuestra muerte tan temprana con daño de tantos como dependen de vos; [...].*
>
> **Juan de Pineda, "Diálogos familiares de la agricultura cristiana", 1589 (España).**